# Issue while adding a config var to an app in Heroku

Tags: heroku

When I try to add a config var to my app in Heroku, it says `Item could not be updated: Unknown Error. Please contact support.` and when I try to contact the support, they say that the support for free apps is the community in StackOverflow.

Does anyone have the same problem ?

Comment: Whats the command you type? Did you try via the Web Dashboard?

Comment: It only works in private navigation ! And yes I use the Web Dashboard not the CLI, I still don't know why but I work this way now